# Does Locale.getDefault().getLanguages() method needs location permission?

Tags: android, permissions, location

I am working on one application that uses Adobe Analytics and I send language settings via `Locale.getDefault().getLanguage()` method. I have received a warning from Google Play service that I am using the location of user and I couldn't find anything else except this one. Is it possible that this method is using user's location?

Comment: Nope. The issue might be in a library you are using.